# Read Excel File with .xlsb extension in vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, xlsb

I need to open and read a binary Excel file with the .xlsb format just to read a few cells from 3 different sheets. I tried this way that I usually use for .xlsx but it is not working on Using workBook As New XLWorkbook(filePath). What is the best way to do this? Preferably without resorting to paid libraries ...   Thank you.

```
    Using openFileDialog1 As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
        If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            txtFicheiro.Text = Path.GetFullPath(openFileDialog1.FileName)

            Dim filePath As String = openFileDialog1.FileName

            Using workBook As New XLWorkbook(filePath)

                Dim workSheet As IXLWorksheet

                workSheet = workBook.Worksheet(0)

                Dim dt As New DataTable()

                Dim firstRow As Boolean = True
                For Each row As IXLRow In workSheet.Rows()

                    If firstRow Then
                        For Each cell As IXLCell In row.Cells()
                            dt.Columns.Add(cell.Value.ToString())
                        Next
                        firstRow = False
                    Else

                        dt.Rows.Add()
                        Dim i As Integer = 0
                        For Each cell As IXLCell In row.Cells()
                            dt.Rows(dt.Rows.Count - 1)(i) = cell.Value.ToString()
                            i += 1
                        Next
                    End If

                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt
                Next

            End Using

        End If
    End Using
```

Comment: And not working means?  Errors, unexpected results, what?

Comment: @Hursey It just says that XLWorkbook does not work with .xlsb files ... But have you ever opened files with this extension?

Comment: Nope, but 20secs on google suggested using OleDB